# Static const getter file giving me an error

Tags: c++, static, constants, getter

Item.h:

```
class Item
{
private:
    static const int price = 5;
public:
    static const int& getPrice();
};
```

Item.cpp:

```
const int& Item::getPrice(){
    return price;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
int main()
{
    Item item;
    cout << item.getPrice() << endl;
}
```

Error: undefined reference to 'Item::price'

Why is this?

Comment: Static members do not belong to objects. `Item::getPrice()` should work.

Comment: Why not `static const int getPrice();`?

Comment: You can also use just `const int price = 5;` it doesn't need to be a `static` class variable as far I can see.